# iOS Allow different screen orientation withouth autorotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to keep a portrait orientation even if user rotate the phone. At the same time, I want to change the orientation with a button.
If I put only portrait as supported orientation in plist and then rotate, application gives me error. If I put all the supported orientation but `shouldAutorotate` method to NO, Application crashes.
So, basically as I can see I can only support multiple orientation if I let the application to autorotate.

Can I achieve what I need?

Comment: what kinda error are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

```
shouldAutorotate
```

this is a get-only property.

what you can do is:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Maybe this is also interesting for you: [how to dissable and enable auto rotate on swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110402/how-to-dissable-and-enable-auto-rotate-on-swift)

Comment: 2018-01-31 09:24:04.602401+0100 OnTheGo[11399:587160] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [UnityLandscapeRightOnlyViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Answer (score -1):

May be the following line of code will work for you. set orientation programmatically.

1. In your Appdelegate class write this code:

   var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
           return self.orientationLock
   }

2.Make custom helper class as follows:

```
struct AppUtility {

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {

        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }

    /// OPTIONAL Added method to adjust lock and rotate to the desired orientation
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        self.lockOrientation(orientation)

        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }

}
```

3. then use it in your desire viewcontroller like:

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   ```
   AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
   // Or to rotate and lock
   // AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait, andRotateTo: .portrait)
   ```

   }

   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool){
       super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

   ```
   // Don't forget to reset when view is being removed
   AppUtility.lockOrientation(.all)
   ```

   }

note: keep remember Require Full Screen option is checked from target settings.

Comment: Hello @MRizwan33, why full screen option must be checked?

Comment: bcz its split the screen. if u wanna split screen then leave it uncheck.

Comment: on ipad device oritation doesn't impact. if u want keep full screen than u need to check this for ipad.

Comment: i just need to change programmatically the orientation WITHOUT the autorotation.